# как подсчитать количество дней оставшихся до определённой даты? PHP

Tags: php

Получилось такое решение, но по условию мне необходимо вводить дату в формате  ’DD-MM-YYYY’. Но если я меняю формат даты, то способ уже не работает.

```
function days($date){
  $now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
  $your_date = strtotime($date);
  $countdown = ($your_date - $now)/ (60 * 60 * 24);
  return $countdown;
}
echo days("2022-12-05");
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем-то у вас рабочий вариант.

Если у вас по условию дата в формате **DD-MM-YYYY** то надо сначала перевести ее в формат **YYYY-MM-DD** и дальше уже по тому варианту, который у вас. Есть.

Один из вариантов может быть

```
$temp = explode("-", $date);
$date = $temp[2] . "-" . $temp[1] . "-" . temp[0];
```

Ну или любой другой вариант где вы конвертируете строку с датой.

Как вариант можно посмотреть на класс **DateTime** и метод **DateTime::createFromFormat**, который позволяет обрабатывать строку с датой по шаблону.

Answer (score 0):

В php уже довольно давно появилось несколько специальных классов и интерфейсов для работы с [датами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php). Их функциональность богаче чем у старых добрых strtotime и date. Например есть метод [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php), который позволяет парсить даты в разных нестандартных форматах.

Если изучите этот функционал, то сможете написать что-то вроде:

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '05-12-2022')
    ->diff(new DateTime('now'))
    ->format('%a');
```